# Question 6th of Chapter -5 Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, farey-sequences

I am trying exercises of the book mentioned in the title and I need help in the question no. 6.

Image of question ->[image]

I tried drawing graph of both the areas, $ S_r$ and $S_{r-1}$, but I don't think I am proceeding in the right direction because then I have to subtract something which is not in the equation I have to subtract. So, I am doing it wrong.

Please give some hints.

Comment: Never post unsearchable images.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in question $6a$ explains which are the lattice  points that differ between the regions $T_{r-1}$ and $T_{r}$. The region $T_{r-1}$ can be visualized by starting from the square that includes all $(r-1)^2$ points with $1\leq x \leq r-1$ and $1\leq y \leq r-1$, then dividing the square in two right triangles by an ideal diagonal traced from the upper left to the lower right vertex of the square, and finally taking the upper right triangle (including the diagonal).  In this way, $T_{r-1}$ includes  $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} k$$=r(r-1)/2$ lattice points.

When we pass from $T_{r-1}$ to $T_{r}$, our triangular region gains the $r^{th}$ row and the $r^{th}$ column, including the point with coordinates $(r,r)$ where they intersect. However, it loses the old diagonal, that is to say the points aligned from the old upper left vertex $(1,r-1)$ to the old lower right vertex $(r-1,1)$. In fact, the region $T_{r}$ has a new diagonal, starting from   $(1,r)$ and ending in  $(r,1)$.

Now the equation tells us that, passing from $T_{r-1}$ to $T_r$:

- we gain the weight of the point with coordinates $(r,r)$, as shown by the term $F(r,r)$;
- we also gain the weights of the $r^{th}$ row and $r^{th}$ column, as shown by the summation
  $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} [f(k,r))+f(r,k)] $$
- we lose the weight of the old diagonal, from point $(1,r-1)$ to $(r-1,1)$, as shown by the summation
  $$\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} f(k,r-k)$$

Comment: In first paragraph everything is clear to me except last line :In this way, $T_n$  includes ($r^{2}$ −r)/2 lattice points. Can you please elaborate that how you counted lattice points in the Upper Right Triangle ( Including Diagonal)?

Comment: I read 2 nd paragraph but it doesn't used the last lune of 1st paragraph but kindly tell how you counted lattice points.

Comment: I think there would be (r) (r+1) /2 such lattice points instead of ( r) ( r-1) /2 such lattice points.

Comment: I calculated by dividing lattice points of square into 3 parts points on diagonal, points below diagonal ( forming a triangle ) , points above diagonal ( forming a triangle).

Comment: The number of points of $T_{r-1}$, calculated in the first paragraph, is $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} k=r(r-1)/2$. That of $T_{r}$ is s $\sum_{k=1}^{r} k=r(r+1)/2$. I edited the question to better explain it.

Comment: for $T_{r-1} $ I am getting r× ( r+1) /2 . Can you please explain your method of counting lattice points?

Comment: can you please tell how you got the formula $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}  k $ as lattice points of $T_{ r-1} $ ?

Comment: For $T_r$, both $x$ and $y$ run from $1$ to $r$. Similarly, for $T_{r-1}$, both $x$ and $y$ run from $1$ to $r-1$.  So for $T_{r-1}$ we have $r-1$ points on the upper row, $r-2$ points on the row immediately below, and so on, until we have $1$ point on the lower row. This leads to $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1}k=r(r-1)/2$. For example, let us consider $r=4$. We have   $T_{r-1}=T_3$, which includes three points on the upper row $[(1,3)$,$(2,3)$, and $(3,3)]$, two points on the second row $[(2,2)$ and $(3,2)]$, and one point on the lower row $[(3,1)]$. So, a total of six points, as predicted by $4(4-1)/2=6$.

Comment: Got it thanks!!